# pass data from parent page to popup

Tags: asp.net, pass-data

I have an asp.net page which launches a child page in another browser window to look like a popup.
I want to pass 2 pieces of data to it from the parent page.
I know ots possible with javascript, but is there a way to do it using C#?

thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that the data is not too big (in sense of actual values) you can simply add it as a parameter to the URL (like `Popup.aspx?Data1=Piece_of_data&Data2=Piece_of_data`).

Otherwise you'd probably want to do the same thing with POST request, it depends on how exactly you are opening the popup ;)